# How to transpose and concatenate an auto-workflow on excel or alteryx

Tags: excel, automation, workflow, alteryx

I have huge sets of data and addresses that run multiple lines. Trying to create a grouping function or tool on excel or alteryx that can transpose and group all of the data in a tabular format without selecting each group individually. Problem is some of the raw data spans multiple rows making a function difficult to create.

e.g

name: belgium holdings

address: 123 european st
paris, France

taxid: 12345

Final result

name               address        taxid
belgium holdings  123 european st 12345
paris, France

This result, but for almost 50 entries. And if i can consolidate all the tabs into one spreadsheet

I've attached an example below [the right is final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzPR2.png)

Comment: Can you clarify exactly the problem or give a larger set of datathat is the issue? Looking at your example, it obviously could be made into a function, however I'm guessing you have more complex challenges to get around. Also understanding the "Rules" is hard. Will each *line* have no breaks in between as shown in the address on example street?

Comment: Use a MultiRowFormula to group records (e.g. increment an integer counter only when you encounter the beginning of a new record), and another to concatenate address lines (within a group). Then CrossTab, grouped by the new counter and using F1 for column headers and F3 for the column values... this should give you the row/column structure that will make ensuing analysis a breeze.